# How should I store this information I am getting from a file?

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, stl

Currently I am looking at a file which has information in this format:

```
header: 
  seq: 313
  stamp: 
    secs: 1488279773
    nsecs: 788520137
  frame_id: ardrone_base_link
batteryPercent: 58.0
state: 2
magX: 74
magY: -32
magZ: 42
pressure: 90927
temp: 427
wind_speed: 0.0
wind_angle: 0.0
wind_comp_angle: 0.0
rotX: 1.34500002861
rotY: -2.72399997711
rotZ: -4.82999992371
altd: 0
vx: -1.59770445708e-40
vy: -3.68179961114e-40
vz: -0.0
ax: 0.0632314383984
ay: 0.0111897774041
az: 0.982218265533
motor1: 0
motor2: 0
motor3: 0
motor4: 0
tags_count: 0
tags_type: []
tags_xc: []
tags_yc: []
tags_width: []
tags_height: []
tags_orientation: []
tags_distance: []
tm: 590774784.0
```

Now as you can see, there are multiple sections, with the header `seq` clearly being an identifier here that can possibly be used in an `stl::multimap`. However as you can see, I want all the information to be stored, including a way to understand that `secs` is a subsection of `stamp` which in turn is a subsection of `header`. Also, the information I get would vary a fair bit, so I cannot make a `struct` which would handle this information.

How would I go about this?

Comment: It looks like valid YAML. If it is a YAML library would take care of all of that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It looks like YAML. For sure. 
If you need a private object - you can create something like that:

```
enum objType {
  OBJ_STRING,
  OBJ_VECTOR,
  OBJ_MAP
}

class DataObj {
public:
   DataObj(const string&, const string&); // Creates object with single name-value data
   DataObj(DataObj *); // Creates object of vector type
   DataObj(const string&, DataObj *); // Created object of map type
   void setObjectKey(const string&);
   void setObjectType(objType);
   void addObject(DataObj *);
   ...
private:
   objType e_type;
   string objData;
   string objKey;
   vector<DataObj *> objVector;
   map<string,DataObj*> objMap;
}
```

So, you can always change data object from string to vector and then - to map upon file parsing. And then recursively get data until you reach single level string object data.

Answer (score 1):

As Biffen commented, you could use a YAML library for this.

If you are looking for a generic way of storing information like this (different data types, nested data, etc), you can either use inheritance to model different types (numbers, strings, or containers of of other data), or use tagged unions that either store a value or a container to more values.

An example of the latter is implemented in https://github.com/nlohmann/json
You could adapt this technique to your needs.

Comment: @thanks for your answer. I guess I could work through an inheritance model, but it wouldn't too wise to spend time on such a thing right now.